# Python loop with condition: using same code whether condition is met or not

Tags: python-2.7, loops, conditional-statements

I have a dict and a list:

```
main = {"one": "apple", "two":"pear", "three":"banana", "four":"cherry"}
conditional_list = ["one", "four"]
```

The conditional list may be empty or contain values (like in the case now). I would like to iterate over the dict "main". BUT: if the conditinal list is not empty, I would like to iterate only over the items that match the conditional list. So:

```
for key, val in mainlist:
    if conditional_list:
        if key in conditional_list:
            do something
    else:
        do exactly the same thing
```

I it possible to set up the iteration in such a way, that I don't have to copy+paste the whole code of "do something" to "else" (the line where it says "do exactly the same thing")? Or to put it in another way: Is there a way to ignore the line "if key in conditional_list" if the condition is NOT met (i.e. the list is empty)?

The thing is, the code "do something" is huge and needs to be updated from time to time, copy+pasting it would make things extremly complicated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
for key, val in mainlist:
    if not conditional_list or key in conditional_list:
        do something
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to pass the key to a doSomething() function

Also, you may have a reason, but it looks like the dictionary is being used backwards; given the context, this may be an apt solution for you:

```
for i in conditional_list:
    doSomething(i,d(i),(i in mainlist))
```